# R Build time series with start date and end vectors

Tags: r, time, series

I'm starting to study time series analysis. I have some df which are composed as follows: each line consists of customer service, having the start date (mse_in), the end date (mse_fim) of the service, and the neighborhood (bairro) where the activity occurred.

```
> mse_df
# A tibble: 484 × 3
       mse_in    mse_fim           Bairro
       <date>     <date>           <fctr>
1  2015-11-03 2016-08-11         Pachecos
2  2013-03-18 2014-10-02       Bela Vista
3  2012-08-08 2015-09-24          Brejaru
4  2014-02-24 2014-12-17            Madri
5  2015-03-30 2015-04-29  Jardim Eldorado
6  2012-07-30 2013-09-19          Brejaru
7  2016-05-24 2017-05-19      Frei Damiao
8  2012-08-13 2015-02-09 Ponte do Imaruim
9  2012-08-08 2014-07-23 Ponte do Imaruim
10 2012-07-30 2012-10-10     Caminho Novo
# ... with 474 more rows
```

I would like to do the time series analysis counting all the clients and another for each neighborhood between January 2012 and April 2017, but I do not know how to produce the necessary time series to start the analyzes. Thanks.